# Ticker timer interrupt max count

Tags: timer, mbed

on this link

https://os.mbed.com/handbook/Ticker

it says, "Note that timers are based on 32-bit int microsecond counters, so can only time up to a maximum of 2^31-1 microseconds i.e. 30 minutes. They are designed for times between microseconds and seconds. For longer times, you should consider the time()/Real time clock."

My question is that this 30 minute limit is only for when an interval of 1 us is being used? something like this

flipper.attach_us(&flip, 1);

In case I have to call an interrupt every 1 ms does this mean the counter can now go upto 30000 minutes? something like this

flipper.attach_us(&flip, 1000);

Also what would happen to the timer after it gets filled does it clear it self on its own and restart or does it through out an error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This question doesn't currently indicate that you have given this timer technology a try - something which is normally expected on this site before the community can get involved. I would suggest you do some experiments and then edit the question to post your code, what you expect to happen, and what is happening in practice.

Comment: I have tried this with 1ms interval, printing an incremental counter and it seems to work fine but to check the limit it would have to be tested for 30000 minutes. 

With 1 us nothing gets printed as I suppose the 1 us interval is too short for the controller to execute the periodic function and also print the output. Tried at 10 and 100 us as well but get nothing at output.

Comment: Thanks for that. The best thing to do now is for you to edit the question to include this new information, and also your relevant code. Hopefully the community will then pick this up and help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function declaration:

```
void attach_us (Callback< void()> func, us_timestamp_t t)
```

"t" is the time between calls. The warning you found in the linked page (https://os.mbed.com/handbook/Ticker) says that the max interval time you can set to is about 30 minutes because "t" is a 32-bit int. 
(I think it is 64-bit in the latest API though. https://os.mbed.com/docs/latest/reference/ticker.html).

When the timer reaches the value specified by “t”, it overflows and triggers the Callback function. It repeats that until you detach it.

If your interval is 1ms, you don't need to worry about the 30mins max limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The page you're linking to is old. Timers are no longer 32-bits, but are 64-bits now; so this is no longer an issue. See the latest version of the `Ticker` docs at https://os.mbed.com/docs/latest/reference/ticker.html .